# How Can I Consume an Externally Hosted Web Service in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, xml, web-services, visual-studio, soapui

We are attempting to consume an externally hosted web service through an internally developed .NET program.  The issue that we have is that we cannot directly reference the URL for the web service through the standard Visual Studio method (Right-click “References” in the Solution Explorer an “Add Service Reference”) as the schema in the web service file (.svc) contains an incorrect address of the URL.

The vendor is aware of this issue but cannot update the attribute value in the schema, however, when we run a test in SoapUI we are able to load the .svc.xml file and update the URL to the correct value and successfully consume the service.  We’d like to be able to load the service schema/xml file in Visual Studio, update the attribute value for the URL and develop our custom program to consume the service.  Is this possible?  If so, how can we do this?

If there are any further questions or any other clarification is needed, just let me know and I'll be happy to get as much more helpful information as possible.

Comment: To clarify, we're using C# with this particular process.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you want to generate webservice proxy classes?

If so, I believe there was similar problem with VS referencing https service. Easiest solution was to save the result of webservice schema query using the browser and then point VS to the file using `file:///` protocol. You can find more in MS article [Creating an XML Web Service Proxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2s8y7bs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)